How to open the wsl tab with cmd in the windows terminal and run a command in linux?
I have been toying with neovim and I want to add nvim as my default editor. Right now I have been using a bash script that opens the terminal with cmd and neovim, but many of my configurations of the wsl are in the arch profile. Is there any way to not only open a tab with an arch profile but also open a file within the ach wsl?Expected behaviour
I have tried to use a bash script to open wsl with the terminal but it opens the command prompt instead of the arch wsl terminal
c:\windows\system32\wsl.exe -e /usr/bin/bash -c "nvim $(wslpath '%1')"
I have also tried using commands like arch nvim $(wslpath '%1') or set the wsl terminal as default and open the terminal with wt then adding the command with nvim $(wslpath '%1'). However, nothing has worked as I need. At best (the first try) it has been opened with the cmd profile instead of the arch wsl.

Hi, I could solve this problem with this bash command
wt -w 0 -p "Arch" -- bash -c "nvim $(wslpath '%1')"
That follows the format
wt -w 0 -p "(WSLDistro)" --bash -c "nvim $(wslpath '%1')"
wt = opens terminal -w 0 = creates new window in terminal if it is already opened -p = opens the terminal's profile (Distro) = the distro's profile --bash = runs a bash script in the terminal -c = writes in terminal "nvim = opens nvim $(wslpath '%1')" = gets the file path in wsl
